# By flashing emmc, beaglebone black not working after second reboot

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I am using Beaglebone black Rev C with Debian OS.I have flashed eMMC using sdcard.
I am facing the issue that whenever I remove SD card and boot the board , it **boots successfully first time** but after next reboot cursor continuously blinking on screen and nothing is happening further.
Please help me now how to resolve it.

Comment: Bizarre.  Have you tried a full shut-down and start-up rather than reboot (as a troubleshooting step, this would not be an acceptable final solution)?  I would try that, possibly even removing your power source for a few seconds after shut-down.  Let us know what happens!

Comment: yes.I tried that way also.But still facing the same issue.

Comment: And just to be clear, you are able to boot from the sd card one or more times, but if you shut down and remove the sd card it will boot from eMMC one time, then freeze up on boot if you try to boot from the eMMC a second time.  Sorry to basically restate your question, it just seems so odd that I want to be sure I have the correct, full picture here before pursuing further.

Comment: yes,with sd card keeping in board I can boot several times. After flashing the board when I removed sd card from board(power-off mode), it boots first time successfully but then I shut down board & power on the board (or even restart the board after first boot) nothing is happening.

Comment: Which image are you flashing to the card? Have you checked the debug UART output yet?

Comment: I am flashing "bone-debian-8.6-lxqt-4gb-armhf-2016-11-06-4gb" on sd card. I just wanted to know how to check the debug UART output as I am newbie in this development.